# jqPlot Cursor follow series line

Tags: jqplot

I have a line graph using jqPlot with one series and several data points across it and smoothed lines. I'm using the Cursor plugin to show crosshairs and a tooltip to show x and y points.

Is it possible to have the cross hairs follow the line on the series? So the horizontal line would fix to the y position of the line and not following the mouse. I see you can get the x/y position of each data point but not of the lines inbetween points.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the built in smoothing options the smoothed data points are stored at:

```
plotObj.series[0].renderer._smoothedPlotData
```

with pixel locations at:

```
plotObj.series[0].renderer._smoothedData
```