# jqplot calculating values inbetween series points

Tags: jqplot

Is there a feature in jqplot that calculates the curve and allows you to display values in between the points in a series?

For example the series below will only display these five values when `showVerticalLine` is set to `true`. I'd like to display each value along the curve with each tick.

```
var data = [['2011-05-03 10:15:30', 25],
            ['2011-05-04 11:30:30', 30],
            ['2011-05-05 10:15:30', 25],
            ['2011-05-06 11:30:30', 33],
            ['2011-05-07 10:15:30', 25]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could approach it in the following way:

1. For each curve segment check against a vertical line for intersection ([some math on line and curve intersection](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.03/senthil1.html), but there is more  on the web I am sure you might even find a ready `JavaScript` method).
2. If they intersect you have the wanted point and you can display its x and y coordinates.

If you use smoothed line option then you could get the points
`plotObj.series[0].renderer._smoothedPlotData`, [as in @Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11269251/613495), and test for example for point line distance and take the closest. Though the first mentioned approach would be more precise.

Comment: Thanks alot for the direction, I got it going.